# use environment variable if set otherwise use default value in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I can do this:

```
MY_VAR:=$(myvar)
```

But what I want is to also define a value for MY_VAR that is used if the environment variable myvar isn't defined. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
# pseudo code
MY_VAR:=if not $(myvar) then someDefaultValue
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming `make` is GNU Make, all the environment variable settings inherited by `make` are automatically registered
as `make` variable settings. See [6.10 Variables from the Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment). So you can just write, e.g.

**Makefile (1)**

```
ifdef myvar
MYVAR := $(myvar)
else
MYVAR := default
endif

.PHONY: all

all:
    echo $(MYVAR)
```

Which runs like:

```
$ make
echo default
default
```

when `myvar` is not defined in the environment; and when it is defined,
runs like:

```
$ export myvar=notDefault
$ make
echo notDefault
notDefault
```

And in case the environment variable and the `make` variable are the same - and why not? - it is simpler still.

**Makefile (2)**

```
MYVAR ?= default

.PHONY: all

all:
    echo $(MYVAR)
```

See [6.5 Setting Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors)

Then:

```
$ make
echo default
default
$ export MYVAR=notDefault
$ make
echo notDefault
notDefault
```

Comment: coool i saw the question mark in makefiles before, didnt realize this is what it does

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code below.

```
MY_VAR=${HOSTNAME1}
if [ "$MY_VAR" = "" ]; then
MY_VAR="DEFAULT"
fi
```

Comment: This is a verbose, and slightly incorrect, restatement of the simple built-in shell notation `MY_VAR=${HOSTNAME1:-DEFAULT}` (the error is that `==` should properly be `=` unless you specifically tell Make to use Bash as the `SHELL`).